# criando um site para medir conhecimento

Tags: html, css3

Olá, estou iniciando meus estudos na web e por enquanto só sei HTML 5 e CSS3, e para medir conhecimento queria saber sobre algum framework que possa me ajudar a fazer um site responsivo com animações de um site fictício por exemplo.

Comment: BootStrap e Materialize CSS são boas escolhas

Comment: Entra de cabeça no jquery e js...

Answer (score 0):

Como eu havia citado a cima, existem dois Frameworks que eu considero os melhores, e mais usados no mercado, porém a quantidade de Frameworks que habitam as profundezas da internet são gigantescas, e com isto vai ficar a seu critério em escolher qual estudar.

**Bootstrap** -

> Desenvolvido pela equipe do Twitter, o Bootstrap é um framework
>   front-end de código aberto (opensource). Em palavras simples, é um
>   conjunto de ferramentas criadas para facilitar o desenvolvimento de
>   sites e sistemas web.
>
> Compatível com HTML5 e CSS3, o framework possibilita a criação de
>   layouts responsivos e o uso de gris, permitindo que seu conteúdo seja
>   organizado em até 12 colunas e que comporte-se de maneira diferente
>   para cada resolução.
>
> Como qualquer outra ferramenta, possui suas vantagens e desvantagens.
>   É importante conhecer e entender suas funcionalidades para saber os momentos certos de utilizá-lo.
>   ***fonte***: http://thiagonasc.com/desenvolvimento-web/desenvolvendo-com-bootstrap-3-um-framework-front-end-que-vale-a-pena

**Materialize CSS** - É uma ferramenta desenvolvida com base nas ferramentas utilizadas pelo próprio google e 100% responsiva, o Materialize CSS também usufrui de um sistemas de GRIDS igual ao Bootstrap, o que facilita a combinação das das ferramentas.

Documentação:
Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/
Materialize CSS: http://materializecss.com/

Obs: Todas as informações foram criadas por minha autoria, as quais foram adicionadas de fora foram postas a fonte.